# operator[] overload in bit-field manipulation?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, bit-fields

I am working on an arduino-like platform (very limited RAM), and I need to use a bit-field. I need to modify a specific bit in a byte, with something like this:

```
OneByte myByte = 0b11101111;
myByte[5] = 1;
```

To achieve this, I wrote the following:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t bit0:1;
    uint8_t bit1:1;
    uint8_t bit2:1;
    uint8_t bit3:1;
    uint8_t bit4:1;
    uint8_t bit5:1;
    uint8_t bit6:1;
    uint8_t bit7:1;
} BitByte;

typedef union {
    BitByte asBits;
    uint8_t asByte;
} BitField;

class OneByte
{
public:

    OneByte();      // default constructor
    ~OneByte();     // delete

    // Assignment operator
    uint8_t& operator[] (const uint8_t pos  );
    uint8_t  operator[] (const uint8_t pos  ) const;

private:
    BitField oneByte;
};
```

and in the .cpp I put

```
// I know a switch case is horrible, but don't want to think too much
// pos shoud always be between 0 and 7
uint8_t& OneByte::operator[] (const uint8_t pos  )  
{
    if (pos < ByteSize)
    {
        switch (pos)
        {
            case 0:
                return oneByte.asBits.bit0;
                break;
            case 1:
                return oneByte.asBits.bit1;
                break;
            case 2:
                return oneByte.asBits.bit2;
                break;
            case 3:
                return oneByte.asBits.bit3;
                break;
            case 4:
                return oneByte.asBits.bit4;
                break;
            case 5:
                return oneByte.asBits.bit5;
                break;
            case 6:
                return oneByte.asBits.bit6;
                break;
            case 7:
                return oneByte.asBits.bit7;
                break;
        }
    }
    // If goes here, do some error handling
}
```

The `uint8_t  operator[] (const uint8_t pos  ) const;` works fine, but the problem is with

```
uint8_t& operator[] (const uint8_t pos  );
```

which fails to compile with the error:

```
error: cannot bind bitfield ‘((OneByte*)this)->OneByte::oneByte.BitField::asBits.BitByte::bit0’ to ‘uint8_t& {aka unsigned char&}’
```

I don't really know what to do in this case... Maybe make another class to wrap this one so I don't use the `operator[]` overload?

Comment: What about simply using a [`std::bitset<8>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead of rolling your own?

Comment: Let me show you some code, http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-omap2/sdrc.c , see how `omap2_sdrc_init` does bit manipulation. Really, when you write something small, low-level, and not-very-public, but with tight time or memory constraint, just write it ugly, and forgive yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been noted you can't bind a bit-field to a non-const reference. Since you're targeting the Arduino using `std::bitset` may not be a viable option depending on how much control you need over functionality or access to the data.

There are a couple of things i want to note though. First I don't recommend using C++ bit-fields for this. They're good if you need named access to the bits but in this case I think there are more maintainable ways to accomplish what you want. Second, returning `uint8_t` or a reference to one from the index operators seems goofy, especially since you're actually working with boolean values.

Since you are working with individual bits you'll need to use a proxy object to sets and retrieve the individual bits without affecting all values in the bit-field. By providing a conversion operator and assignment operator for `bool` types you can provide seamless access to the bit values. Something like the following should work for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

class Bits
{
    typedef std::uint8_t value_type;

    value_type   bits;

    struct Twiddler
    {
        Twiddler(value_type& value, size_t bitIndex)
            : value(value), mask(1 << bitIndex)
        {}

        Twiddler& operator=(const Twiddler&) = delete;
        Twiddler& operator=(bool bit)
        {
            value = value & ~mask | static_cast<value_type>(bit ? mask : 0);
            return *this;
        }

        operator bool() { return (value & mask) != 0; }

    private:

        value_type& value;
        value_type mask;
    };

    struct ConstTwiddler
    {
        ConstTwiddler(const value_type& value, size_t bitIndex)
            : value(value), mask(1 << bitIndex)
        {}
        ConstTwiddler& operator=(const ConstTwiddler&) = delete;
        operator bool() { return (value & mask) != 0; }

    private:

        const value_type& value;
        value_type mask;
    };

public:

    Bits() : bits() {}
    Bits(value_type bits) : bits(bits) {}

    size_t size() const { return sizeof(bits) * 8; }

    Twiddler operator[](size_t index)
    {
        if (index >= size())
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("Invalid bit index");
        }
        return Twiddler(bits, index);
    }

    const ConstTwiddler operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        if (index >= size())
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("Invalid bit index");
        }
        return ConstTwiddler(bits, index);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you verry much ! I had to change some things, but it finally worked (ishh)

Answer (score 1):

From [class.bit]:

> A non-const reference shall not be bound to a
>   bit-field (8.5.3).

So you simply cannot bind a `uint8_t&` to any of your bits. You should consider instead using [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), which solves this problem by using proxy objects ([`std::bitset::reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/reference)).

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I am looking for, but it seems the std::bitset dosen't exist for AVR-GCC ? Instead of using a proxy I think ill just use an ugly setBit and getBit like @user3528438 suggested !